# Images are not loading in a webview ViewPager

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I am developing a simple app using ViewPager.  It has content and images in a webview.  ViewPager has a number of pages, all pages have the same data.

content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/content_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

SampleActivity.java:
    package com.android.sample;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    public static ViewPager contentPager;
    public static ContentPagerAdapter  contentPagerAdapter;
    public static List<String> mPages;
    public static SampleActivity context;
    int _position;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content);
        context = this;
        mPages = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i =0;i<20;i++) {
            mPages.add("<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><html><head><style type=\"text/css\"> img { max-width:100%; max-height:100%; } </style></head><body><p>   "+ i +" <br>  <img alt=\"\" class=\"alignleft\" height=\"160\" src=\"http://yourstory.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/vakil_search_n.jpg\" style=\"margin: 5px;\" title=\"vakil search\" width=\"280\" /><em>Lawyers at </em><a href=\"http://yourstory.in/?s=vakilsearch\" target=\"_blank\"><em>VakilSearch </em></a><em>shed some light</em></p><p>The categorisation of an expense as revenue expenditure or capital expenditure has been a perpetual ground for litigation between assessees and the authorities.</p>");
        }
        contentPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.content_pager);
        contentPagerAdapter = new ContentPagerAdapter();
        contentPager.setAdapter(contentPagerAdapter);
        contentPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageListener());
        contentPager.setCurrentItem(0 );     
    }
    class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int state){
                //Log.d(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged  state  " + state+ " _position  "+_position + "webView"+webView);
        }
        public void onPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
                //Log.d(TAG,"onPageScrolled Target webViewPrevious : " + webViewPrevious + " webView " + webView );
        }
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            _position = position;

            //  TextView pageNumberView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.page_no);

            //pageNumberView.setText("" + (position + 1) + " of " + (viewNumber));
        }
    }


    public  class ContentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        String html="";
        WebView webView;
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            //clearALlVedios();

            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((RelativeLayout) view);

        }
        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPages.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(context);

            webView = new WebView(context);

            String content;
            try {
                content =  mPages.get(position) + "<br>  ";

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                content="";
            }

            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            /// webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);

            webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

            //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            //  webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            //webView.getSettings().
            /*int scale = ((int) (100 * ( webView.getScale()))) + 10 ;

                Log.i(TAG, "zoom scale  : "+ scale);

                webView.setInitialScale( scale );*/

            //  webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            //  webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            //webView.setInitialScale(140);

            html = "<p >"+ content+ " </p>";

            ll.setPadding(8, 8, 2, 8);
            final String mime = "text/html";
            final String encoding = "utf-8";            
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url != null && ((url.startsWith("http://")) || (url.startsWith("https://")) || (url.startsWith("www.")))) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            ll.addView(webView);

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(ll);
            ll.setTag(position);
            return ll;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }
        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        }
        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
}
```

The html has different types of content (text + image) with same structure...

Problem: when the activity starts, images are not shown. When I tap the zoom-in, the image shows, when I tap zoom-out, the images are not shown.

I searched, but I didn't find any help.

Comment: Please provide all the activity's code and any other layout files. This will help considerably.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see the `setContentView` in your code. A `WebView` is another view like `ImageView`, `TextView`.. so you need to use the `setContentView` function.

Note that you're using to different clients `WebViewClient()` and the `WebChromeClient()` you need to know the difference between them, the main difference is that the `WebViewClient` is more configurable.

You can load web content in at least 2 ways.

The first one is "Load the given data into the `WebView` using a 'data' scheme URL" (using the function

```
webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
```

The other way is directly loading the URL of the webpage. To begin, I recomend you to do a normal webpage, save it in the assets folder or in the SD card and then load it from there.

Like this:

```
wview.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/yourfolder/yourpage.html");
wview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourpage.html");
```

Hope, this helps a little.

Comment: thanks for your replay. i am using PagerAdopter  following is complete  activity code is

Comment: i got where is problem, when webview is adding to layout (ll.addView(webView);). if we reading webview from xml file no issue, any one how to solve it